# NSTableView just like Finder

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I still have a long way to go learning Cocoa. I'm trying to learn to code a Table view just like the finder where there is a small icon to the left of the file listing. #1 Its not clear to me if those are two columns in a row or if that type of operation is handled as 1 column.

If someone could point me to a good, easy to follow example, I would appreciate it. I was able to follow one example and I can drag and drop files onto the view but it only displays the [files lastPathComponent]. I wasn't sure how to add the icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to subclass NSCell if you want this. Here is a good example:

[NSCell Image and Text Sample](http://www.martinkahr.com/2007/05/04/nscell-image-and-text-sample/)

Comment: Are there any other resources you can think of? I looked at the link and it was difficult for me to follow. Thanks

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html - look at ImageAndTextCell.h - you should be able to just drop this class into your project and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help--the apple dev section on Cell Based tables helped me begin to understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 3):

While yes you could do as sosborn suggests, however if you're already using OSX 10.7 Lion, you can now  (and should!) use NSViews instead. And specifically you can subclass NSTableCellView.

Personally, I would watch the WWDC video titled "View Based NSTableView Basic to Advanced" available here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

This also includes sample code that will get you going.

Comment: View based tables are so overdue, and great, but if you want 10.4-6 users then you will end up having to do it both ways and test both ways, and not save yourself any trouble at all.

Comment: My Code needs to support Leopard and forward, so I can't do anything that is Lion specific